# rqt_graph not dispalying all the topics?

Tags: ros, rqt-graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`1.png` shows a list of nodes and topics currently running, but `2.png` is rqt_graph where many topics and `/rosout` node are not being displayed .Could someone please tell me what exactly is going wrong here ? Thanks in advance

[image: 2.png]

[image: 1.png]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253961/rqt_graph-not-dispalying-all-the-topics-?/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-02-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have `rqt_graph` configured to hide:

- Dead sinks (ie: subscriptions that have no publisher)
- Leaf topics (ie: publishers with no subscriptions)
- Debug (ie: all topics used for logging msgs and related infra)

Try turning those on and off, you'll see the 'missing topics' appear.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-07**:
it works now . Thanks !!! I should've played around with those options a bit to figure it out .

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-21**:
This was very helpful.